# Nginx restrict access

Tags: nginx

I have a website running on nginx and I want to allow only private IPs to certain parts of it and both private and public to the other parts, for example:

wwww.mydomain.com/first - allow only private IPs
wwww.mydomain.com/second - allow private and public IPs

I tried many options, currently I have the following configuration, but it's blocking both public and private:

```
location ^~/first {
allow 172.0.0.0/24;
deny all;
return 404;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to restrict access to static files, the problem could be caused by `try_files $uri =404` (default) which might match if the files exists in given location. Following example might look overcomplicated but demonstrate nginx capabilities and should be pretty much bulletproof.

I'm assuming following directory structure:

```
/var/www/
├── chroot
├── _first
│   └── index.html
├── index.html
└── _second
    └── index.html
```

and site configuration:

```
# proxy server for accessing real files
server {
  listen 8080;
  index index.html index.htm;
  server_name _;
  root /var/www;
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  index index.html index.htm;
  server_name _;
  root /var/www/chroot; # empty jail directory
  try_files index.htm =404; # non-existing location 

  location ^~ /first {
    # in case that $uri exists, deny rule is not applied
    allow 127.0.0.1/32;
    deny all;
    try_files $uri @proxy;
  }

  location @proxy {
    rewrite ^/first(.*)$ /_first/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  }

  location ^~ /second {
    rewrite ^/second(.*)$ /_second/$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect     off;
    proxy_set_header   Host $host;
  }

  # shoud match all not above
  location / {
    deny all;
    return 403;
  }
}
```

Now some basic test, when you're accessing from whitelisted IP:

```
$ curl -L localhost:80/first
first
```

public endpoint

```
$ curl -L localhost:80/second
second
```

any other URI should result in `403`, like trying to access "private" URIs:

```
$ curl -L localhost:80/_first
<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not working for me. I'm trying to restrict access to /first first but even when I leave the location ^~/first/ empty I get 404, I also tested it with allow all and I get the same response 404, even when remove return 404. I can't figure this out.

Comment: @HSC see the updated answer. Rewrites are not necessary, that's just to demonstrate slightly more complex scenario. I can remove it if it's too confusing.